# Writing binary format on console in FORTRAN under windows

Tags: console, binary, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I am trying to write in binary format on console in FORTRAN under windows but I can not do it. I know I can use Open() function and use Form='Unformatted' to open a file and write in binary format. But I need to write on the console not external file.

My project is to use pipe mechanism to communicate between a FORTRAN and a C++ programs. Part of the communication is to send large amount of double precision numbers. Right now I am sending the actual numbers. If I can send them as binary format it will speed up the process.

Is there any way to write in binary format on console in FORTRAN? I tried to typecast the numbers by char() function but it is only for integer not double!

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The trick is to stuff the data into strings and use ordinary list directed write..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027067/write-unformatted-binary-data-to-stdout

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply george but the page you mentioned is for Linux not windows! do you know how to do it under windows?

Comment: it should be the same, try it and see what problems you run into.

Answer (score 0):

If it is F77, try something like this

```
      program writer
      double precision x
      character(len=8) xalt
      equivalence(x,xalt)
      x = 10.0
      do i = 1, 10, 1
         x = -10.0 * x
         write(*,'(A)', advance='no') xalt
      end do
      stop
      end
```

If you want to use it for F90 without the equivalence, you will have to use the transfer function to transfer from double precision (or real*8 or real*2 depending on implementation) to character.

I don't really know how big your datastream is but if you are writing to console, the OS might insist on inserting a CR/LF after X characters.  That could completely mess up your input stream.  Ever thought of doing this using MPI or sockets or pipes?

Comment: `advance='no'` is a little advanced for F77.  The fortran runtime might do interesting things to the data stream as well if part of the representation of the double precision value looks like a line feed.

Comment: old school you do write(*,'(a,$)').  The $ is not strictly standard f77 but a common extension.

Comment: for completeness i have found you cannot READ stdin with this approach, exactly due to the issue of spurious data bits being interpreted as an EOF.